# Problem with elementary os juno after wake up

Tags: release-juno, nvidia, suspend, performance

I have some sirious problems with my elementary os juno after waking up (unlocking). When I first boot computer everything works just fine, system is fluid and very responsive. But, at the first time I lock/unlock system it starts to slow down and gets very unresponsive and choppy.

PC is very powerful

- Cpu: i7-8700k
- Gpu: nvidia 1080TI (NVIDIA Driver Version: 415.27)
- Ram: 32gb ddr, Hard drive
- kingston ssd

The only way to solve the problem is to restart window manager with gala --replace & from virtual terminal and after restart everything works just fine.

What do you think, what can cause such a problem and what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

srda1989,

Welcome to the Elementary OS forum.

The first thing I would look at would be to determine what processes may (or may not) be hammering your powerful system.  One way to do this is through the terminal.

Go to Applications -> Terminal (or Win+T)
At the terminal prompt type the following command:

```
top
```

This will show you (in real time) which processes are hammering away at your system.  The important things to look for are (1) anything that shows a high percentage in the %CPU column and (2) the %Cpu(s): line.  Especially the xx.x id number.  Theoretically, that number should be close to 100 as possible.

If, on the other hand, some process is grabbing a high percentage of the CPU then it gives us some place to focus on solving your unresponsive issue.

Finally, the top command will continue to run until you type the following letter:

```
q
```

Good luck!

Comment: I noticed descent amount of cpu power used by gala process, but nothing exaggerated. Also it's worth to mention, when I restart gala with "DISPLAY=:0 gala --replace &" everything become smooth again.